# How to add a method to a class at runtime in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to debug a mysterious crash I'm seeing in Crashlytics, but haven't been able to reproduce myself.

The error message looks like this:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[NSNull compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e911bc30
-[NSOrderedSet initWithSet:copyItems:]
```

[Here is the full stacktrack if interested](https://pastebin.com/hZtU0QHp)

Because I haven't been able to pinpoint the origin of the crash, I thought I would add a new method to `NSNull` in order to further debug it via logging.

However I'm not sure how to do it. I think I'd need to add a `compare` method to `NSNull`, but I have limited knowledge of objc. I got the idea [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58348992/1689950). The proposed solution for a similar problem looks like this

```
BOOL canPerformAction(id withSender) {
    return false;
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   Class class = NSClassFromString(@"UIThreadSafeNode");
   class_addMethod(class, @selector(canPerformAction:withSender:), (IMP)canPerformAction, "@@:");
}
```

How could I do this in Swift for adding `compare` to `NSNull`?

Comment: Why do you have `NSNull` in your ordered set in the first place?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I'm not sure, I assume it's coming from a 3rd party library (likely either Bolts or Parse), but currently I don't know where the ordered set comes from or why it has NSNull in it

Comment: Doesn't the stack trace tell you which library it comes from? Also, can't you define methods on `NSNull` via an extension, using `@dynamic`?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yeah I can try to add a method via an extension, but I'm not really sure what the compare method is supposed to accept or return. If you look at the stack trace I posted, you'll see that the symbols for Parse and Bolts packages weren't captured in this crash for some reason, so it's hard to pinpoint where the crash comes from. It looks like it's probably from the Parse library, but I've no idea what the library was doing when it happened.

Comment: Agreed. It doesn't look like the crash is coming from your app's code. You should report this bug. Is Parse even maintained these days??

Comment: @JacobRelkin the parse server repo is well-maintained, but the client sdks have fallen by the wayside unfortunately. I'll probably end up just building out my own API to reduce client-side use of their libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `compare` method to `NSNull` like this:

Objective-C:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static inline NSComparisonResult compareNulls(id self, SEL _cmd, NSNull *other) {
    if([other isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        return NSOrderedSame; // Nulls are always the same.
    }

    return NSOrderedDescending;
}

@implementation NSNull (Comparisons)

+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        const char *encoding = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s@:@", @encode(NSComparisonResult)] UTF8String];
        class_addMethod([self class], @selector(compare:), (IMP)compareNulls, encoding);
    });
}

@end
```

Swift:

```
// Add this code to your AppDelegate.swift file:
import ObjectiveC

fileprivate func compareNulls(_ self: AnyObject, _ _cmd: Selector, _ other: AnyObject) -> ComparisonResult {
    if other is NSNull {
        return .orderedSame
    }

    return .orderedDescending
}

fileprivate func addNSNullCompareImplementationIfNecessary() {
    let sel = NSSelectorFromString("compareNulls:")
    guard class_getMethodImplementation(NSNull.self, sel) == nil else {
        return
    }

    let types = "i@:@"
    class_addMethod(NSNull.self, sel, imp_implementationWithBlock(compareNulls), types)
}

// Add this line to your -didFinishLaunching: function:
addNSNullCompareImplementationIfNecessary()
```

*This is only a temporary solution that will stop the crashes.*

I would nevertheless encourage you to a) file a bug report, and b) continue investigating why this happened - clearly having an `NSNull` in this case wasn't expected by Parse...

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I think I've figured out where the issue is coming from in the Parse library, so I will open an issue there as well.